# Unbounded operator $T $ is bounded below when $\overline T$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

How to prove the following?

A densely defined symmetric operator $T$ in Hilbert space $H$ has a closure $\overline T$ which is bounded iff both $T,-T$ are bounded below (there exist  constants $c,c' \in \mathbb{R}$ with $(Tx,x)\geq c||x||^2$ and $(-Tx,x)\geq c'||x||^2$).

Comment: @julien $c\in R$

Comment: [See here, p. 198](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch8.pdf). The definition of bounded below requires $c>0$ in every paper/book I've seen so far.

Comment: @julien http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#CITEREFPedersen1989

Comment: It's interesting that functional analysis people don't have the same definitions depending whether they talk about bounded or unbounded operators. I think you should add that to your question.

Comment: @julien any clue for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perdersen's book, *Analysis Now*, where this observation is made, bounded below is also called semibounded. I'll go with the latter, as I've spent too many years giving bounded below the more restrictive meaning it has in (bounded) operator theory.

Essentially, this result boils down to: $T$ symmetric is bounded if and only if $AI\leq T\leq BI$ on its domain for some $A,B\in \mathbb{R}$ .

> **Lemma:** a symmetric operator $S:H\longrightarrow H$ is bounded if and only if $S$ and $-S$ are semibounded.

**Proof:** For a symmetric operator $S:H\longrightarrow H$, we have
$$
\|S\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(x,Sx)|
$$
where each $(x,Sx)$ is real. So if $S$ is bounded, we have
$$
-\|S\|\leq (x,Sx)\leq \|S\|\qquad\forall \|x\|=1
$$
hence
$$
-\|S\|\|x\|^2\leq (x,Sx)\leq \|S\|\|x\|^2\qquad\forall x\in H.
$$
Thus $S$ and $-S$ are semibounded.

Conversely, if $S$ and $-S$ are semibounded, we get $A,B$ real numbers such that
$$
A\|x\|^2\leq (x,Sx)\leq B\|x\|^2\qquad\forall x\in H.
$$
Setting $M:=\max\{|A|,|B|\}$, we obtain
$$
-M\|x\|^2\leq (x,Sx)\leq M\|x\|^2\iff|(x,Sx)|\leq M\|x\|^2\qquad\forall x\in H.
$$
Hence $\|S\|\leq M$ and $S$ is bounded. QED.

**Direction $\Rightarrow$:** if $T$ is closable with bounded closure, then  the domain of $\overline{T}$ is $H$ and $\overline{T}$ is still symmetric. So the above entails that $\pm \overline{T}$, a fortiori $\pm T$, are semibounded.

**Direction $\Leftarrow$:** if $\pm T$ are semibounded, then the argument in the proof above applies and yields $\|T\|\leq M<\infty$ where $\|T\|$ is the sup of $|(x,Tx)|$ over the unit sphere of the domain of $T$. It follows that $T$ is bounded and extends continuously to a bounded operator on the closure of its domain, i.e. $H$. In other words, $T$ is closable with bounded closure.

**Note:** the crucial formula $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(x,Tx)|$ follows from Cauchy-Schwarz in one direction, and from polarization+parallelogram law in the other direction. [See here](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch8.pdf), p.198, for a proof in the bounded case. The general symmetric case follows by the same argument, essentially.

Comment: @89085731 So? What do you think?

Comment: Since T is unbouneded,how can u use that crucial fomular

Comment: @89085731 If $T$ is truly unbounded, this gives $+\infty=+\infty$. Which is true.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the question ask on the page "
[On boundedly invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395787/on-boundedly-invertible)
" is almost similar to the one above.