# The Kernel of unbounded operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $T$ is a densely defined operator from a subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ to a Hilbert space $K$, how to prove that $\mbox{Ker}(T)=\mbox{Ker}(T^*T)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $T$ is only densely defined does not change the proof of the bounded case $T\in B(H)$. Indeed, if $x$ belongs to $\mbox{Ker} T$, then $Tx=0$ belongs to the domain of $T^*$. Now if $x$ belongs to the domain of $T^*T$, a fortiori it belongs to the domain of $T$. So the following holds like in the bounded case.

> $$Tx=0\;\Rightarrow \; T^*Tx=0\;\Rightarrow\; (x,T^*Tx)=\|Tx\|^2=0\;\Rightarrow\; Tx=0$$

Comment: thks.I am also struggling with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357257/unbounded-operator-t-is-bounded-below-when-overline-t-is-bounded.Can u give me some hint?

Comment: i don't understand why we can do $(x,T^*Tx)=(Tx,Tx)$

Comment: @89085731 Good question. If $T^*Tx=0$, to begin with, it means that $y=Tx$ belongs to the domain of $T^*$. By definition of $T^*y$ via Riesz representation, the linear form $x\longmapsto (y,Tx)$ is equal to $(T^*y,x)$. Now replace $y$ by $Tx$.

Comment: @89085731 Anf this one? Did it convince you?

Comment: maybe i need u help again.i search the website and can just find the case of idf/dx.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359064/spectrum-of-differentiation-operator-on-h-l20-1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Of course one inclusion is clear. For the other direction, use the fact that $\langle T^{*}T x, x \rangle = \| Tx \|^2$.

Comment: sorry, i know it is a little rude,but can u see this question.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359064/spectrum-of-differentiation-operator-on-h-l20-1

Answer (score 0):

One direction is trivial. For the other, consider an element in the kernel of $T^*T$, and the definition of the adjoint, and of the properties of the inner product.