# On boundedly invertible

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:X\to X$  be a bounded and invertible linear operator. Show that $\inf_{x: \|x\|=1}\|T(x)\|\geq M$  if and only if $\sup_{x: \|x\|=1}\|T^{-1}(x)\|\leq N$, where $M,N\ge 0$.
 .

Comment: You need to restrict your $\inf $ and your $\sup$ over the unit sphere, for this to make sense.

Comment: could you help me to rephrase this question? thanks!!

Comment: The proper phrasing is $\inf_{\|x \|=1}\|Tx\|>0$ if and only if $\|T^{-1}\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|T^{-1}x\|<\infty$. This does not require $T$ to be bounded. But note that it is automatic when $X$ is Banach and $T$ bounded.

Comment: is it right to say that $MN=1$ in the above context?

Comment: If you follow TZakrevskiy's argument, it shows that $\sup=\frac{1}{\inf}$. And that's the best formulation. Since it includes the case $\infty=\frac{1}{0}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's show it in one direction:

$\displaystyle \sup_{x:\|x\|=1}\|T^{-1}(x)\|= \sup_{x:\|x\|>0}\frac{\|T^{-1}(x)\|}{\|x\|}.$ Now replace $x$ by $T(y)$ - we can do it because our operator is  invertible; furthermore, for each $x$ such $y$ is unique. Hence our equality continues 
$\displaystyle  = \sup_{y:\|y\|>0}\frac{\|y\|}{\|T(y)\|}=\sup_{y:\|y\|=1}\frac{1}{\|T(y)\|}=\frac{1}{\inf_{y:\|y\|=1} \|T(y)\| }=\frac{1}{M} $.

The proof in the other direction is done likewise.

Comment: You've actually already shown both directions.

Comment: And the fact that $T$ is bounded is not used.

Comment: @julien indeed, we don't need this fact, thank you.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I see that you use this fact in your proof.

Comment: @user78412 I mentioned it, but in fact, it's sufficient to have invertibility; boundedness is not used.

Comment: thanks for your quick response!!